# MeshLab preprocesses meshes while importing them

Tags: graphics, 3d, mesh, meshlab, 3d-modelling

I have installed a fresh copy of MeshLab by executing the following commands:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab
bash meshlab/install/linux/linux_setup_env_ubuntu.sh
bash meshlab/install/linux/linux_build.sh
```

I would like to load some meshes of the [ModelNet40](https://modelnet.cs.princeton.edu/) dataset, which contains `*.OFF` files.
Now, when I load a mesh into the image viewer [meshlabjs](https://www.meshlabjs.net/), then the file seems to look correct:

[image]

But when I load the same mesh into `MeshLab` itself, then it is displayed with strong artifacts and it seems like there happened a strong decimation:

[image]

**Question**: Why do these differences in displaying appear? Is it possible, that there are filters automatically applied, from older installations of MeshLab on my mashine? How can I fix this, to display the "correct" looking meshes inside `MeshLab` instead?

**Note**: If I export the "broken" mesh and save it somewhere else and display it inside `MeshLabJS`, then it looks the same broken way with artifacts as it did in `MeshLab` before.

It is interesting to mention, that the number of vertices and faces is the same in both cases: Correct geometry and incorrectly loaded geometry.

I have checked `MeshLab > Filters > Current Filter Script` , but the list there is empty. I am on `Ubuntu 19.04` and I use `MeshLab` version `2020.03`.

Here is another example. Incorrectly loaded geometry:

[image]

Correctly loaded geometry:

[image]